# Can the MK802 III use an ethernet connection instead of wifi?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, usb, networking

Just got the MK802III and got some Ice Films related apps installed.  A lot of the content is streaming, so I'm wondering if I use an ethernet cable to connect to my router via USB to the 802, if I'll get less lag?

Comment: Is it use Android 4.0? Googling displays, what 4.1 is used (it's for tags).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From forums:

> tsuda
>
> > Quote:
> >     Originally Posted by stevhorn
> >     I can confirm this works with the MK802II, but I don't know about the MK802III.
>
> http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Apple...661773412.html
>   Yes, it works on the MK802II. The III has the same Ethernet config screen in Settings so it should be the same. I will try it this weekend and let you know.